# Flexbox issue in angular 4

Tags: angular, sass, flexbox, angular2-template

I need to have fixed header and fixed sidebar.. I am doing this with flexbox in another html css.. I works perfect.

https://codepen.io/Vugar94/pen/bWLPLM

I paste the code in here

```
<body>
   <header>
       header
   </header>

   <section id="content">
       <div class="sidebar" style="color: #fff">
           sidebar
       </div>
       <div id="main_content">
           content
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

scss

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

header {
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 80px;
}

#content {
   background-color: #ccc;
   flex: 1;
   overflow: auto;
   display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
   width: 200px;
   background-color: #000;

}
#main_content {
   flex: 1;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}

body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;  
}
```

But when I apply this code to angular4.. it doesnt work and it drives me crazy. This is my angular code

**in report.component.html**

```
<header>
   <app-header></app-header>    
</header>

<section id="content">
   <div class="sidebar">
       <app-aside></app-aside>
   </div>
   <div id="main_content">
       <app-content></app-content>
   </div>
</section>
```

in style.scss  I apply style that i wrote erlier..

in report.component.scss I wrote nothing..
please help me
If you want to check for this issue make a projet with angular-cli and see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside report component wrap all elements into div with class "flex-container" than make the div **"display: flex"**.That might help you ;)